# Inserting a column from view to a table in psql

Tags: mysql, psql

I have a table- "location" like below(ID is unique here):

```
id | street_number | zip

1     123
2     324
3     34
4     57
```

And I have VIEW - "loc_view" like below:

```
id | zip_code

1     10023
2     10043
3     10021
4     10089
```

How can I add the zip_code values from VIEW to the zip column of "location" table.

Comment: A 'view' can **always** be thought of as a 'read-only' table. So you can 'join' to it, use it in a 'subquery' etc. Nothing special about it when using it in 'queries'.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO location (zip) (SELECT V.zip_code
                            FROM view V
                            JOIN location L
                            ON V.id=L.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a `JOIN` with the view and then perform `UPDATE` on table `location`

```
   UPDATE location l 
   JOIN loc_view lv ON l.id = lv.id
   SET l.zip = lv.zip_code
```

Comment: @math, are you sure? see a demo fiddle which proves that it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa51a/1

Comment: Sorry,Let me check again. Not sure what the error is.Thanks

Comment: @math, problem was I spelled `location` incorrectly as `lacation` and so the error. That's corrected and edited in answer. Try the edited query and do consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.